# Assigning values to signals within for-generate statements

Tags: vhdl, variable-assignment, generate

I cannot figure out why the signal assignment for "sig2" in the following example won't happen successfully, while for "sig1" it does. With the rising clock edge "sig2" becomes 'X'!

What is the reason?

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

entity Test_tb is
end entity Test_tb;

architecture Structural of Test_tb is

    signal sig1 : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal sig2 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal clk : std_logic := '0';

begin
    clk_generate: process is
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;        
    end process clk_generate;

    gen_label : for gen_indx in 0 to 3 generate
    begin
        process (clk) is 
        begin
            if clk = '1' and clk'event then
                sig1 (gen_indx) <= '1';
                for loop_indx in 0 to 1 loop
                    sig2 (gen_indx * 2 + loop_indx) <= '1';
                end loop;
            end if; 
        end process;
    end generate gen_label;

end architecture Structural;
```

Comment: This question doesn't a [mcve], leaving readers without the ability to readily replicate the problem nor validate any answers. A simple solution would be to replace the loop statement with `sig2(gen_indx * 2 + 1 downto gen_indx * 2) <= (others => '1');`. The issue is the *longest static prefix* used in identifying drivers during elaboration of the design hierarchy. Loop parameters are dynamically elaborated, the longest static prefix of the original would be sig2.

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks for the notice. I edited the code to become instantly verifiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, when a signal is assigned inside a for loop, it is assumed that the driver affects ALL elements of the array (or record). This is because it cannot work out the bounds of the for-loop at elaboration time, as it is a run time concept. This is different from a generate loop where the bounds can be deduced at elaboration time.

So you need to remove the for loop from inside the process, or create a signal local to the generate loop which is assigned to the outer sig2. eg:

```
gen_label : for gen_indx in 0 to 3 generate
  signal local_sig  : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
    process (clk) is 
    begin
        if clk = '1' and clk'event then
            sig1 (gen_indx) <= '1';
            for loop_indx in 0 to 1 loop
                local_sig(loop_indx) <= '1';
            end loop;
        end if; 
    end process;

    sig2(gen_indx*2+1 downto gen_indx*2)  <= local_sig;
end generate gen_label;
```

Comment: More precisely drivers for a process are identified during elaboration (IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.2). This can involve locally static expressions, globally static expressions but the *longest static prefix* (8.1) does not include dynamically elaborated expressions (14.6 Dynamic elaboration para 2 "a) Execution of a loop statement with a for iteration scheme ..."). The longest static prefix in the original is the name sig2 in `sig2 (gen_indx * 2 + loop_indx)` and here `sig2(gen_indx*2+1 downto gen_indx*2)` which depends only on static expressions.